# How long does it generally take to stop feeling climber's elbow?

Tags: rock-climbing, climbing, bouldering, injury

I've been climbing 1-2 times / week (usually once) for about a month. After each time I climb, I feel joint pain in my elbows. From my understanding, this is likely [Tennis Elbow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_elbow).

Slowly but surely, the pain seems to be becoming less intense, and also last a bit shorter each time I climb. My question is, how long does it generally take to stop feeling elbow pain altogether after a climb? I am aware that there are mitigating techniques for alleviating joint pain as mentioned in this question: [What can I do to help relieve joint pain in fingers after climbing?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/296/what-can-i-do-to-help-relieve-joint-pain-in-fingers-after-climbing/6897#6897). My question, however, is related to how long it generally takes to feel **no** elbow pain for someone who is climbing 1-2 times / week.

Comment: This is not answerable in general, as both developing elbow pain from climbing as well as recovering from it is an individual thing. However I think it is save to say that you should change your climbing routine if you always experience pain - lower the intensity, i.e. less steep and easier grades.

Comment: You need to talk to a physiotherapist for this, not opinions on the internet.

Comment: @Separatrix Maybe I have, and I just wanted to hear other peoples' opinions as well...

Comment: make sure you properly warm up before you start climbing. rotate your elbows, and start with very easy climbs, to avoid pulling on your tendons cold. I usually only get painful elbows when I skimp on the warmup time